# jQuery select box maximum in select box group

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-slider

Good morning,

I need a "Range" picker for jQuery.
Is there one in jQuery or jQuery-UI?

For example:

[image: example of slider wish]

I have 3 select boxes with a sum of 2.
In one select box of the select box group, i select the amount 1.
Then the other select boxes in that group have only one value "1".

The second (right) example:
I have 4 Select Boxes with a sum of 4.
First i select the Amount "2" in one select box of that select box group.
Then the other boxes have only 1 and 2 as choice.
I select 2? Then the others are empty "0" or i select 1, then i could select +1 at the others.

Like this:

```
<selectgroup maximum="2">
    <select name="first" />
    <select name"second" />
    <select name"third" />
</selectgroup>
```

or that (right example):

```
<selectgroup maximum="4">
    <select name="first" />
    <select name"second" />
    <select name"third" />
    <select name"fourth" />
</selectgroup>
```

they generate the options self.

**Its like this one => http://www.humblebundle.com/weekly <=, but with groups and with select boxes.**

[image: humblebundle slider]

**Thank you in Advance!**

Comment: Library or software recommendations are discouraged here and this question is likely to be closed as not constructive. See also [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/169187)

Comment: hmm. sorry... but i find no software if i google "jquery multiple slider plugin" or "jquery group slider" ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create sliders using the jQuery UI slider, documentation found at http://jqueryui.com/slider/ .

You can then bind to the `.change` event, for which the documentation is found at http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-change .

In that callback you can use the `.value` method to adjust the value of the other sliders dynamically, documentation found at http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value .

Let me know if that is helpful, and if that makes sense :)

Comment: Its helpfull ;) Before that, i used a self-maded function with javascript only. But they doesnt work 100%. Now with your tip it works 100% :P